# Insert an element (table) to the cursor position

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to create a new Table element with custom style and append it to the current cursor position in the document. I saw that it is possible to get the current position with:

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
```

that returns a Position object. Position class provides a method to append Text to the current position:

```
cursor.insertText('ಠ‿ಠ');
```

but from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position) I can't see a way to insert a generic Element (a Table in my case) instead of simple text.

On the other hand there is a method of the class Body that allows to append a Table to the end of the document, but it is not possible to specify a custom position.

Somebody can help?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get some workaround?

Comment: I posted an answer to a [duplicate question of this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945638/insert-a-table-into-google-doc-at-cursor-position/40675038#40675038)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've pieced it together. I have a function `createComponentTable` that takes a boolean `atCursor`, which if false appends a table at the end of the document, and if true inserts a table at the cursor position.

(I also have a function `doAlert(text)` elsewhere that I can turn on/off for debugging.)

```
function createComponentTable(atCursor) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var thisTable;

  if (atCursor) {
    var cursor = doc.getCursor();
    if (cursor) {
      var element = cursor.getElement();
      if (element) {
        var parent = element.getParent();
        thisTable = body.insertTable(parent.getChildIndex(element) + 1);
      } else {
        doAlert('Cannot insert there');
      }
    } else {
      doAlert('Could not get cursor position');
    }
  } else {
    thisTable = body.appendTable();
  }

  if (thisTable) {
    // add rows and cells to thisTable here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a STUB on it, eg. `cursor.insertText('%%MY_TABLE_WILL_GO_HERE%%');`, then continue the function to find this line and place the table.

Comment: Can you add code example, as it's not working for me.